# ReferenceError: MediaStream is not defined with Jest and Vue Typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a component in Vue (written on typescript) that has a property which type can be a `String`, `Blob` or `MediaStream`, like below

```js
@Prop({ type: [String, Blob, MediaStream] }) readonly srcObject?: string | {};
```

When I run a unit test that calls this component it throws an error with the following message:

```sh
    ReferenceError: MediaStream is not defined

      66 | })
      67 | export default class Player extends Vue {
    > 68 |   @Prop({ type: [String, Blob, MediaStream] }) readonly srcObject?: string | {};
         | ^
      69 |   @Prop({ type: String }) readonly mediaType?: string;
      70 |   @Prop({ type: Boolean }) readonly srcIsBeingRecorded?: boolean;
      71 |   @Prop({ type: Boolean }) readonly autoplay?: boolean;
```

I tried different approaches like add `MediaStream` object to the global `window` mock but unfortunately, it was unsuccessful. After that, I tried to replace `MediaStream` for `window.MediaStream` in order to avoid the `... is not defined ...` message.
I found on the web but without success. I don't understand why jest doesn't found the `MediaStream` type or why it crashes.
I will be very gracefully if anyone can help me with this error or show me the right way to do that.

Information about dependency versions below:

```sh
λ dazh [work] at  feature/global-handling !?
→ npx tsc --version                                                                                                                                                                             [a81cdad]
Version 3.5.3

λ dazh [work] at  feature/global-handling !?
→ npx vue --version                                                                                                                                                                             [a81cdad]
@vue/cli 4.3.1

λ dazh [work] at  feature/global-handling !?
→ npx jest --version                                                                                                                                                                            [a81cdad]
24.9.0

λ dazh [work] at  feature/global-handling !?
→ cat package.json | grep '"vue":'                                                                                                                                                              [a81cdad]
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem regarding MediaStream interface. My solution was to use `mockImplementation` for `MediaStream`. Here is a snippet of my suite configuration:

```
 beforeAll(() => {
    window.MediaStream = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      addTrack: jest.fn()
      // Add any method you want to mock
    }))
  })
```

I hope this can be helpful

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, currently I'm not working on that project anymore and I can't test your answer, but I will try to reproduce the issue to confirm your approach.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with this.. https://app.sli.do/event/2pkRsTdk78o91XCjAzhKo7/embed/polls/d99765d9-0c7e-4993-9e9d-efff1424a7df